# Programmatically configure Azure DevOps project settings

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking for a way to automate/script Azure DevOps project creation. I know that I can use [VSTeam PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VSTeam) to create a project, but it does not provide a way to programmatically set project settings (the ones on the screenshot below). Is there a way to do that with PowerShell or AZ CLI? In particular I'm looking for a way to control/change these two settings:

- Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
- Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Rest API:

1. How to use PowerShell with rest API: [Modify Azure Devops Test Case Parameters Through REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65835349/modify-azure-devops-test-case-parameters-through-rest-api)
2. Rest API Methods: [General Settings - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/general-settings/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1); [General Settings - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/general-settings/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Answer (score 1):

To create a project you will need to send a POST to `https://dev.azure.com/<devopsOrgName>/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0-preview.3`

with a body like the below. To get the "template type" value used in the body, you will need to set a GET to `https://dev.azure.com/<devopsOrgName>/_apis/process/processes?api-version=5.0-preview.1`

`        {

```
        "description":  "Tailspin Toys",

        "name":  "Tailspin_TOYS",

        "capabilities":  {

                             "versioncontrol":  {

                                                    "sourceControlType":  "Git"

                                                },

                             "processTemplate":  {

                                                    "templateTypeId":  "24268e03-7eed-4ac0-a178-700881565b99"

                                                 }

                        }

    }`
```

To change specific settings, that you can't find in the documentation, I would suggest using the developer tools in your browser (f12). Watch the network tab and you should see the requests going when you change your setting.

In this instance, I can see the below request when I try these settings

URL: `https://dev.azure.com/<devopsOrgName>/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery`

Type: `POST`

Body:

`{ "contributionIds":["ms.vss-build-web.pipelines-general-settings-data-provider"],"dataProviderContext":{"properties":{"enforceJobAuthScopeForReleases":"false","sourcePage":{"url":"https://dev.azure.com/<devopsOrgName>/<projectName>/_settings/settings","routeId":"ms.vss-admin-web.project-admin-hub-route","routeValues":{"project":"<projectName>","adminPivot":"settings","controller":"ContributedPage","action":"Execute","serviceHost":"495d404e-cdeb-496a-8496-fccf9df3d9fa (<devopsOrgName>)"}}}} }`

Azure DevOps REST isn't the most documented, but when used with your browser develop tools, I haven't found something I couldn't set.

Comment: not sure why the format is so bad :(